# Unable to signup with social login in Baasbox

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, baasbox

I'm new to Baasbox.
I have followed the documentation and created the following below code to sign up with social login.

Here is my code of sign up with token available from respective social networks.

```
$scope.createUserWithBaasbox = function(t,social,isLink){

    var token = t;
    var headers = {'X-BAASBOX-APPCODE':1234567890}
    if(isLink){
        alert("entered if");
        headers['X-BB-SESSION'] = auth.getToken();
    }
    alert("entered $apply method");
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        headers: headers,
        url: serverUrl+"/social/"+social+"?oauth_token="+token+"&oauth_secret="+token,
        data:{}
    }).success(function(data){
        alert("success");
    if(!isLink){
       alert("success"+JSON.stringify(data));
        var userSessionValue = data['data']['X-BB-SESSION'];
        //alert(userSessionValue);
        var visibleByRegisteredUsers = data['data'].visibleByRegisteredUsers;
        if(visibleByRegisteredUsers.email == undefined){
            alert(JSON.stringify(visibleByRegisteredUsers));
            visibleByRegisteredUsers.email = data['data'].visibleByTheUser.email;
            //alert(visibleByRegisteredUsers.email);
            visibleByRegisteredUsers.type = "SUBSCRIBER";
            visibleByRegisteredUsers.redeemedCount = 0;
            visibleByRegisteredUsers.name = data['data'].visibleByTheUser.name;
            visibleByRegisteredUsers.dateOfBirth = "";
            visibleByRegisteredUsers.emailSubscription = true;
            //alert("heyyy"+JSON.stringify(visibleByRegisteredUsers));
            visibleByRegisteredUsers.shareCount = 0;
            if(social == 'facebook'){
                visibleByRegisteredUsers.gender = data['data'].visibleByTheUser.gender;
            }
            else{
                visibleByRegisteredUsers.gender = "";
            }
            //alert(JSON.stringify(visibleByRegisteredUsers));
            $http({
                method:'PUT',
                url: serverUrl+"/me",
                data:{"visibleByRegisteredUsers" : visibleByRegisteredUsers},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                          'X-BB-SESSION' : data['data']['X-BB-SESSION']
                }
            }).success(function(data){
                alert(data);
                //TODO:local storage has to be implemented
                $state.go("app.dummy");
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            })
            .error(function(data){
                   alert("error block is",data);
                   //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            })
        }
        //alert("not entered into if loop");
        //TODO:local storage has to be implemented
        $state.go('app.dummy');
       //auth.setUser(data["data"].user,{"sso":social,"auth_token":token,"auth_secret":token},data["data"]["X-BB-SESSION"]);
       //$location.path("/posts")
    }
    else{
       //alert("loaf from exixting");
       //auth.getLogins().push(social);
    }
    }).error(function(data){
       alert("error block is:"+JSON.stringify(data));
       console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
    alert("before $scope.$apply");
}
```

Its executing the http method and going into the error function and returning data as " ".
Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put

```
<access-origin="*">
```

in config.xml.
So it is not allowing http requests to get response